Bash on mac os appending carriage returns to values
I am a beleaguered linux developer thrust into a task on a mac-os AWS ec2 machine. I have been working on a bash script in this environment, and I am running into something I cannot figure out how to program around.  When I assign thusly:
myHome=`pwd`

, the resulting variable $myHome has carriage returns (\r) at the end which I cannot seem to remove using tr or sed. Further, in my script if I create a directory
mkdir /opt/myApp/subDir

they are all created as /opt/myApp/subDir? with that extra ? appended.
The ec2 tells me (sw_vers) the os is version 13.6.9, build 22G830
I imagine there must be some way to deal with these unwanted characters, but I am stumped. Can anyone advise?

bash doesn't do this. You almost certainly created the script on a Windows machine, it uses CRLF newlines.

Use tr -d '\r' scriptname > scriptname.new to remove them.
